# Linking div with anchor tag in HTML5

Tags: html, css

I have coded one block like this:
The HTML:

```
<a href="#">
    <div class="aw">
        <div class="b1">Text</div>
        <div class="b2">Long Text</div>
        <div class="b3">Text</div>
    </div>
</a>
```

The CSS:

```
.aw{
  color:#AAA;
  background-color:#EFEFEF;
  width:332px;
  height:58px;
  margin:0 auto;
  border:1px solid #EFEFEF;
}
  .b1{
    display:inline-block;
    height:58px;
    width:58px;
    float:left;
  }
  .b2{
    display:inline-block;
    height:58px;
    width:198px;
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
  }
  .b3{
    display:inline-block;
    height:58px;
    width:58px;
    float:right;
  }
```

I am using *overflow:hidden* and *text-overflow:ellipsis* for **class=b2**.

What's happening is the text in one div (**class=b2**) is showing in one line without wrapping the text.

Any quick help/tips?

Comment: Can you also post the css class definitions for these tags?

Comment: Try adding this white-space: nowrap; in the class where you have text-overflow: ellipsis and overflow: hidden. Also your width is a 198px, you might want to increase the length of "Long text" to see the effects

Comment: Seems to work for me, Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/caykA/

Comment: @JerryJones - If it really doesn't work for you, it would probably be useful to let us know what browser (and version) you're testing this in.